# Cannot write a file in the remote server

Tags: php, streamwriter, remote-server

Im trying to write to a textfile in my remote server, i havnt done this before and currently im not getting any out put on the textfile, i have allowed reading writing executing for all in the permission tab. following is my code, can ull check is there anything wrong(textFile is in the same directory),

```
echo "attributes: " . print_r($attributes["$attributeKey"], true) ."\n";
$file = "test.txt";
$write = ("wording2 ".$attributes["$attributeKey"]."\n");
file_put_contents($file, $write, FILE_APPEND);
```

the echo is working but not anything else

Comment: make sure file having 0777

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the chmod of the file

Comment: Do you get any warnings?

Comment: yes file does have 0777 permission

Comment: var_dump(file_exists($file)); var_dump( file_put_contents($file, $write, FILE_APPEND) );

Comment: no warning just not getting write...